# Force IntelliJ project to use Scala compatible with Java 6

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, classloader

I have this project in IntelliJ IDEA which uses Scala. I need it to be compatible to run on Java v1.6. I configured the project as such, and I even only have Java 6 in my development environment. However, when I build the project and run it I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: scala/Function1 : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at myproject.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

It appears as so there's still some class in my project compiled for Java 8. Could it be that the Scala libraries I have are compiled for Java 8? These are the libraries downloaded by IntelliJ IDEA. How can I solve this?

Comment: What version of scala are you using and what are you using to build your project (maven, sbt, etc.)?

Comment: [Don't use scala 2.12](http://scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0#scala-212-overview)

Comment: Standard IntelliJ IDEA Scala project, I'm not sure what the build system is (sort of a Java newbie here). I've tried so far with Scala 2.10 and 2.11. I suspect IDEA is downloading scala already compiled for Java 8. Cause I don't have Java 8 in my system (I used to but not anymore, to get rid of any possible interference in this matter).

Comment: Can you post your build.sbt? Did you check the project settings in intellij to make sure everything is correct? F4 shortcut

Comment: Recent versions of most of the Scala lib won't be compatible

Comment: Project settings is configured to use java sdk 1.6 and scala sdk 2.10.6. Anything else I should check for? Also, I can't seem to find a build.sbt anywhere in my project tree, including inside the `.idea` directory.

Comment: @Ernesto well, you need to have the scala version defined somewhere. Are you using sbt or maven? how are you compiling the project?

Comment: I'm using the IDE (IntelliJ IDEA). Via the project module settings I select the scala version I want, and the IDE downloads it and manages it. I usually prefer to control these kind of stuff myself, but bing a newbie in all this I have no idea how to do this outside of this IDE. (I would use vim if I could).

Comment: More context @nmat: this is an old project we're rebooting, but no one in the current team directly worked on it when it was on several months ago. However someone here not directly related to the project recalls that they used an older version of the IDE, and the scala version was not managed by the IDE. Scala was installed via homebrew (OSX), and the IDE was configured to use the scala installed by homebrew. However now the IDE seems to not work that way, and it only supports managing the scala versions itself. We don't control where it downloads it from, and that may be the problem.

Comment: So we downloaded an older version of the IDE, but then we realized is not the version of the IDE the piece that changed the behavior, but the version of the Scala plugin that gives the IDE support for working on Scala. Perhaps installing an older version of the plugin? But we don't know how to do that. The IDE manages the plugin installation. Oh man I hate IDEs!

Comment: @Ernesto try to see if the project  works on a terminal so we can rule out the system configuration and focus just on the IDE configuration. Run it either with "sbt run" or "maven run" or something like that, it depends on what build tool the project uses

Comment: I have no maven or sbt commands available in the command line, just checked. I've been running this as `java -jar my-app.jar`. The project's build process has configuration to generate a jar with the whole app, scala included in it. Apparently where they'll run this in production is run this way too, and the environment does not have scala, so scala is bundled in the .jar

Comment: Yes, but where does the .jar come from? Something must build it and it is not javac.

Comment: It's the IDE that builds it, sorry, I'm such a java newbie that I know I'm probably sounding dumb. But from my perspective, what builds the .jar is the IDE when I click the "build artifacts" menu option. The project is configured to build this .jar in the project module settings. In this configuration you specify what libraries to include (scala, etc), what JVM to target.

Comment: I'm open to switch over to Eclipe's Scala IDE or anything else to make this work. I just need this project to be built as a standalone .jar that includes scala in it, plus a couple of .jar dependencies bundled as well. The final goal is to be able to run it in the production environment with a command line `java -jar myapp.jar`.